# Can get and be be interchangeable or not?

Tags: grammar

Actually I am confused between get and be as there are so many sentences in which get can be replaced with b without changing their meaning. So I just want to know what are the differences between get and be? And when can I interchange them without changing the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

In many contexts *to **get*** (followed by *[adjective]* or *Past Participle]* used adjectivally) is simply an equivalent alternative to *to **be** [ADJ]*. But note that to some speakers in some contexts, it will be seen as a somewhat "colloquial" usage that should be avoided in formal contexts.

If the "adjectival PP" element refers to an "internal" state, rather than the result of the subject being acted upon by an external agent, the ***get*** form isn't usually very idiomatic...

> 1: *If I fail I will **be** disappointed*  - natural English)
>    2: ? *If I fail I will **get** disappointed* - an "unusual" construction

I'd say the reason for that is because *to **get** [verbed]* more strongly alludes to *undergoing the **process** of being "verbed"*, whereas *to **be** [verbed]* normally references *the **end result** [of having been "verbed"]*. So if we compare...

> 3: *The turkey will **be** cooked at midday tomorrow*
>     4: *The turkey will **get** cooked at midday tomorrow*

...I'd say #3 is more likely to carry the sense of the cooking process being ***finished*** (that's when the turkey will come ***out*** of the oven and be ready to eat), whereas #4 is more naturally understood as a reference to when it'll go ***in*** the oven (and ***start*** to be cooked).

---

The second "distinction" given above is perhaps easier to see with continuous verb forms...

> 5: *Please put the children to bed. They're **being** tiresome*<sup>1</sup>
>    6: *Please put the children to bed. They're **getting** tiresome*

...where #5 is more likely if the children have been ["acting up"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/act%20up) for some time, but #6 more strongly implies they're just ***starting to become*** unruly.

---

<sup>1</sup> Arguably my *first* distinction above is undermined by the fact that *They're **being overexcited*** isn't very idiomatic here, whereas *They're **getting overexcited*** is perfectly natural. Maybe this reflects a third distinction, whereby we avoid two consecutive instances of [TO BE] in favour of plain *They **are / They're** overexcited*, unless the context strongly implies some outside agency *currently causing* the altered state. For example,...

> 7: *They're being overexcited **by Grandpa**, who's getting a little drunk and playing boisterous games with them*.

Answer (score 0):

*Get* has many meanings, one of those is *become*.

This is different than *be*.  When you say *X gets Y* or *X becomes Y*, you are concerned with both the previous and current state of Y and you are also expressing that a change is happening.

When you say *X is Y* you don't have a concern with any previous state, and aren't trying to say anything is changing.